# Easier way to do iterator arithmetic on string copies

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I have a copy (`result`) of a string (`format_`) and then I use `std::find` on the original string, but I cannot use iterators obtained by this on the string copy. This results in some cumbersome code. for example:

```
std::string result = format_;
auto it = std::find(format_.begin(), format_.end(), '%');
auto diff = it - format_.begin();
auto pos_it = result.begin() + diff;
result.insert(result.erase(pos_it, pos_it + 2), right.begin(), right.end());
```

Here if I attempt to use it as an iterator rather than just for math I will get segmentation fault. If two strings are identical, why cannot you "share" iterators?

Comment: @Piotr it is the return value of std::find. the code above just replaces substring with right

Comment: The iterators may internally use pointers and the two strings have different memory locations. Maybe consider using the index position in the string rather than iterators. The string's `find*()` functions can work with index positions.

Comment: @Piotr std::find(format_.begin(), format_.end(), '%')

Comment: @Piotr yes i do result = format_ at the beginning of code

Comment: The answer has already been given (use positions, not iterators), but I wonder why you have to perform the find operation on the original string after creating a copy, and then reuse the results for the copy. This sounds a lot like a flaw in the program design itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can not share iterators between strings (even if they are identical) because they occupy separate memory locations and iterators may use memory pointers internally to access the strings' elements directly.

As an alternative you can use index position offsets into the strings.

Perhaps something like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::string right = "INSERT";
    std::string format_ = "some % text";

    auto pos = format_.find('%', 0); // pos is std::string::size_type (not iterator)

    std::string result = format_;

    if(pos != std::string::npos)
        result.replace(pos, 1, right);

    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```